# sqoop import query error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Tags: mysql, impala, sqoop2, sqoop

I am trying to pull data from a MySQL database into Impala with the following sqoop command.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<ip>:3306/mydb --username user --password pass --fetch-size -2147483648 --query 'select (id,action,object,time) from events WHERE $CONDITIONS and id > 0' --hive-table events --hive-import --target-dir /user/cloud/joinedres --split-by id --num-mappers 1
```

The error I am getting is

```
Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s).
```

Prior to that the `SqlManager` reported `WHERE (1 = 0)` as part of the `Executing SQL statement`

Comment: What is in $conditions?

Comment: Since I'm running this in parallel, the documentation (https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) says I should use this `$CONDITIONS` token

Comment: I would check the resulting sql command, I suspect sg goes wrong with the substitution of the split field criterion.